# TileWMS layers with openlayers 3 return 400 error with some zoomlevels

Tags: tiles, openlayers

I have 2 TileWMS layers in my system which work well with some zoom levels and do not work with other zoom levels.

each non-working layer return this error:
400: X,Y values for the tile index were calculated to be {546.0380800062516, -354.8241599711327} which had to be rounded to {546, -355} and exceeds the threshold of 10%. Perhaps the client is using the wrong origin ?

the returned x,y values in the error message of each tile are different.

These two layers were working well with all zoom levels of openalerys 2.
Also, I use the same resolutions array which I used with openlayers2.

other layer types are working well with the same projection and the same resolutions array in openalyers3

Comment: Do you have a live example people could look at?

Comment: I found the problem :) .. check the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem :)

I must set tileGrid to ol.source.TileWMS.

```
var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
    urls: geowebcacheURL,
    params: {
        'LAYERS': 'the layer',
        'SRS': projection,
        'FORMAT': 'image/gif',
        'TRANSPARENT': 'true'
    },
    serverType: 'geoserver',
    tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.XYZ({
        extent: [x1,y1,x2,y2],
        resolutions: [res1,res2, ...]
    }),
});
```

Openlayers3 builds custom resolutions array if you don't attach your array so tiles urls will have wrong bbox. openlayers2 was used the resolutions array of map options but openlayers3 does not do that and you must assign it for every TileWMS source